# Common Lisp Shebang Script Gives "Command Not Found"

Tags: macos, common-lisp, sbcl, shebang

I'm tyring to run a Common Lisp shebang script (test.lisp) on MacOS using SBCL. The script is below:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/Cellar/sbcl/1.5.6/bin/sbcl --script
(write-line "test")
```

I ran chmod +x on the script to make it executable, and when I run it I get:

```
./test.lisp: line 2: write-line: command not found
```

I made sure my SBCL path was correct. I originally tried /usr/local/bin/sbcl, but that gave me the same error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's a very bad idea to put such a specific path into the shebang as version 1.5.6 will get updated and that command will fail, so you are better off using `#!/usr/bin/env sbcl` and you probably don't need `--script` (not sure - don't know anything about lisp).  What happens when you run `/usr/bin/local/Cellar/sbcl/1.5.6/bin/sbcl --script test.lisp`?  If you get the same effect then it's not a shebang issue.

Comment: Using #!/usr/bin/env sbcl --script worked! I did need the --script, or it just threw me into the SBCL repl. Thanks much

Comment: I think you had `/usr/local/bin` mixed-up with `/usr/bin/local` anyway.

Comment: That was just a typo in the post, thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use such specific paths in shebang script lines, especially if they contain version numbers, as the location/version of those binaries are likely to change and break the script.

Instead use `/usr/bin/env` to find the executable, and in your case that's:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sbcl --script
```

Comment: I realize this question is tagged MacOS, but for completeness sake do note that this solution is not portable to many (the majority?) of Linux distros at present. SBCL requires the `--script` argument, but coreutils [only gained the ability to handle passing multiple arguments to `env` (via the `-S` flag) in version 8.30](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399690). Ubuntu 18.04 is currently on version 8.28 for example.

Comment: @AnOccasionalCashew The point of the answer was to move away from using specific paths of the script interpreter to using `/usr/bin/env` and was nothing to do with `SBCL` (whatever that is).

Comment: Your answer works on MacOS but **will not work** on many Linux distributions at this time. SBCL is the specific Common Lisp implementation being used to run the script in this case. That's important because SBCL in particular **requires** passing the `--script` argument, but current commonly deployed versions of `env` are unable to handle multiple arguments. I do appreciate your general intent, as well as that this doesn't apply on MacOS. Just be aware that such scripts are unfortunately not portable to many Linux boxes for the time being.